# What is the difference between BroadcastReceiver and an IntentFilter?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

Is `BroadcastReceiver` allows an app to receive video streams from live media sources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `BroadcastReceiver` is an Android component which allows you to register for system or application events. All registered receivers for an event are notified by the Android run time once this event happens.

An `IntentFilter` specifies the types of intents to which an activity, service, or broadcast receiver can respond to by declaring the capabilities of a component.

`BroadcastReceiver` does not allows an app to receive video streams from live media sources.